# how to make a loading start bar in Vaadin

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin

Hey to know how to make a progress bar on start up of vaadin application to load data like the way of Flash or FLEX

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [progress indication components](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ProgressIndicators) of vaadin. You'll find [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.progressindicator.html) an example.

The question is, how you calculate your data load progress?!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer , No the question how to make a progress bar as a splash Screen on start up of vaadin application

Comment: @user986586 vaadin already provides this with a rotating progress indicator, so you probably just need to override it.

Comment: Yes you are right , i tried to ovverided trough the method writeAjaxPageHtmlMainDiv but didnt do what i want